# How Do I Center my Nav Bar

Tags: html, css, center, navigationbar

I have a question.
How would I center a nav bar with the following code?
You can see the nav bar at mineflow.us/hitest

```
<div align="center"><div class="special_container last"><div class='m_html' ><style><!--@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700);#cssmenu { background: #FFFFFF; margin: 0; width: auto; padding: 0; line-height: 1; display: block; position: relative; font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;}#cssmenu ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; display: block;}#cssmenu ul:after { content: ' '; display: block; font-size: 0; height: 0; clear: both; visibility: hidden;}#cssmenu ul li { margin: 0; padding: 0; display: block; position: relative;}#cssmenu ul li a { text-decoration: none; display: block; margin: 0; -webkit-transition: color .2s ease; -moz-transition: color .2s ease; -ms-transition: color .2s ease; -o-transition: color .2s ease; transition: color .2s ease;}#cssmenu ul li ul { position: absolute; left: -9999px; top: auto;}#cssmenu ul li ul li { max-height: 0; position: absolute; -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out; -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out; -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out; -o-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out; transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out; background: #2E2E2E;}#cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:after { display: block; position: absolute; content: ''; height: 10px; width: 10px; border-radius: 5px; background: #000000; z-index: 1; top: 13px; right: 15px;}#cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:before { display: block; position: absolute; content: ''; height: 0; width: 0; border: 3px solid transparent; border-left-color: #ffffff; z-index: 2; top: 15px; right: 15px;}#cssmenu ul li ul li a { font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; text-transform: none; color: #000000; letter-spacing: 0; display: block; width: 140px; padding: 11px 10px 11px 20px;}#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > a,#cssmenu ul li ul li.active > a { color: #4cb6ea;}#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover:after,#cssmenu ul li ul li.active:after { background: #4cb6ea;}#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul { left: 170px; top: 0;}#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul > li { max-height: 72px; position: relative;}#cssmenu > ul > li { float: left;}#cssmenu > ul > li:after { content: ''; display: block; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0; background: #2E2E2E; -webkit-transition: height .2s; -moz-transition: height .2s; -ms-transition: height .2s; -o-transition: height .2s; transition: height .2s;}#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a { padding-right: 40px;}#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after { display: block; content: ''; background: #ffffff; height: 12px; width: 12px; position: absolute; border-radius: 13px; right: 14px; top: 16px;}#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before { display: block; content: ''; border: 4px solid transparent; border-top-color: #4cb6ea; z-index: 2; height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; right: 16px; top: 21px;}#cssmenu > ul > li > a { color: #ffffff; padding: 15px 20px; font-weight: 700; letter-spacing: 1px; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 14px; z-index: 2; position: relative;}#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after,#cssmenu > ul > li.active:after { height: 100%;}#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a { color: #000000;}#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:after,#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:after { background: #000000;}#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:before,#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:before { border-top-color: #ffffff;}#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul { left: 0;}#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul > li { max-height: 72px; position: relative;}#cssmenu #menu-button { display: none;}@media all and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) { #cssmenu > ul { max-height: 0; overflow: hidden; -webkit-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out; -moz-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out; -ms-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out; -o-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out; transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out; } #cssmenu > ul.open { max-height: 1000px; border-top: 1px solid rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.25); } #cssmenu ul { width: 100%; } #cssmenu ul > li { float: none; } #cssmenu ul li a { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; padding: 12px 20px; } #cssmenu ul > li:after { display: none; } #cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:after, #cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:before, #cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:after, #cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:before { display: none; } #cssmenu ul li ul, #cssmenu ul li ul li ul, #cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul { left: 0; position: relative; } #cssmenu ul li ul li, #cssmenu ul li:hover > ul > li { max-height: 999px; position: relative; background: none; } #cssmenu ul li ul li a { padding: 8px 20px 8px 35px; color: #ffffff; width: auto; } #cssmenu ul li ul ul li a { padding: 8px 20px 8px 50px; } #cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > a { color: #000000; } #cssmenu #menu-button { display: block; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; padding: 15px 20px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 700; font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: 1px; color: #ffffff; cursor: pointer; } #cssmenu #menu-button:after { display: block; content: ''; position: absolute; height: 3px; width: 22px; border-top: 2px solid #ffffff; border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff; right: 20px; top: 16px; } #cssmenu #menu-button:before { display: block; content: ''; position: absolute; height: 3px; width: 22px; border-top: 2px solid #ffffff; right: 20px; top: 26px; }}--></style><div id="cssmenu"><ul><li class="last"><a href="http://www.mineflow.us/home"><span style="color: rgb(125, 125, 125);"><i class="icon-home"></i> Home</span></a></li><li><a href="http://mineflow.us/forum"><span style="color: rgb(125, 125, 125);"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Forum</span></a></li><li><a href="http://mineflow.us/shop"><span style="color: rgb(125, 125, 125);"><i class="icon-book"></i> Donate</span></a></li><li><a href="http://mineflow.us/vote"><span style="color: rgb(125, 125, 125);"><i class="icon-star"></i> Vote</span></a></li><li class="last"><a href="http://www.mineflow.us/status"><span style="color: rgb(125, 125, 125);"><i class="icon-signal"></i> Status</span></a></li><li class="last"><a href="http://www.mineflow.us/staff"><span style="color: rgb(125, 125, 125);"><i class="icon-globe"></i> Staff List</span></a></li></ul></div><div align="center"><span style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 24pt; color: rgb(255, 0, 0); "><br></span></div> </div></div></div>
```

Comment: Format your HTML, you have it all in one line above.

Comment: One line codes are good but there is a point when they are too long.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zk2qT/) I made JSFiddle, but you should format the code next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#cssmenu{display: inline-block;}
```

btw. use JSFiddle next time, please.

Comment: Thx!
I'll be sure to use it next time :)